# Summation of a series where n is odd

Tags: summation

**Find the sum of a series** 
$$\ \rm 1^2+2(2)^2+3^2+2(4)^2+5^2.......+2(n-1)^2+n^2$$
**where n is odd**

**Attempt**

I tried 
$$\ \rm \sum^n_1 [2(n-1)^2+n^2] - 2\sum^\frac{n-1}{2}_1 [2(n-1)^2+n^2]   $$
but the answer is coming wrong.

The reasoning behind my procedure is that the expression $\ \rm \sum^n_1 [2(n-1)^2+n^2]$ will calculate the sum of all terms up til $n$ and the expression $\ \rm -2\sum^\frac{n-1}{2}_1 [2(n-1)^2+n^2]$ will erase the terms for which $n$ was even.

Can someone provide me some hint necessary for the correct answer and also provide a little insight towards the flaw in my working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $n = 2k+1$ for some integer $k$ then $k = \frac{n-1}{2}$ so your series becomes 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(2k+1)^2 + 2(2k)^2$$

Pretty self explanatory after this.